# Empathy logs into chat networks, without beeing started?

Tags: empathy, startup-applications

I have Empathy installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3. I appear to be online in the chat networks when my computer is connected to the internet. However, I did not even start Empathy, at least not manually.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of gnome shell and allows (at least in theory) for better integration with the new GUI.  You can log out of chat by using the selection box under your name in the top-right menu (change setting to unavailable).

Under 'preferences' in Empathy is a box marked 'Automatically connect at startup'.  If you uncheck this, Empathy should not sign you in to your chat accounts at log in.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I like the behaviour, now that I have some control over it

Comment: Please upvote and accept the anser.

Comment: Sorry, just learned how that works.

Answer (score -1):

If you just only want to make Empathy start but not login in your account, check their preferences.

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find "broadcast preferences". It is maybe because I use Gnome?

Comment: Please read the question completely before answering.

Comment: I did it. What was the problem? Gnome3 != Gnome Shell right?

Comment: Gnome3 defaults to gnome shell.  The "fallback mode" (similar to gnome2) will still display the gtk3+ menus.  He is clearly not running unity, however.

Comment: Ubuntu with Unity still uses Gnome3. Gnome3 is not a desktop environment (Gnome Shell, Gnome Classic are). In his question, he didn't say anything about the desktop environment he was using, but ok.